# Get caps from pipeline

Tags: java, gstreamer

I am new to GStreamer and I try to get Caps property from pipeline in Java. If i try in command line this pipeline

`gst-launch-0.10 -v --gst-debug-level=2 filesrc location="C:/Dokumenty/Eclipse/rtsp_test/trailer.mp4" ! decodebin2 ! queue ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=::1 port=5000 sync=true`

it works fine and return this caps, which I needed

`/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3175930633, clock-base=(uint)3850186239, seqnum-base=(uint)8531`

But I dont know, how to get this caps in Java from pipeline

```
pipe = Pipeline.launch("filesrc location="C:/Dokumenty/Eclipse/rtsp_test/trailer.mp4" ! decodebin2 ! queue ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=::1 port=5000 sync=true");
```

Are there any methods how to get udpsink0 from pipeline?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `Bin` (the parent class of `Pipeline`), you'll see there are a few ways to get individual elements. The most simple way is to use: `Bin.getElementByName("udpsink0")`.

A more generic way would be to call `Bin.getSinks()` and then grab the first result from the list. This way the code will still work even if you use a different type of sink.

Once you have the `Element` object you can get the pad using `Element.getStaticPad("sink")` and then finally you can get the `Caps` object with `Pad.getNegotiatedCaps()`.

For more information check out the javadocs, which can be found at: https://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/downloads/list

In short:

```
Element sink = pipe.getElementByName("udpsink0");
Pad pad = sink.getStaticPad("sink");
Caps caps = pad.getNegotiatedCaps();
```